# Trying to force user press enter

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a auto whatsapp message sender, I create this code that take me to whatsapp window:

```
String smsNumber = "number"; // E164 format without '+' sign
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and I need to create the auto enter. Can someone show me example of something that can help me to press the enter button?

Answer (score 0):

When you start an other `Activity` through an `Intent` you basically kill your running application. How will you then send your "auto enter"? I would suggest that you develop your app as a [forground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), then when you send the user to WhatsApp, you can highjack the keyboard and send the key command(enter).

You can use this to send keyboard commands if device is rooted.

```
public static void inputKeyEvent(String keyCodeString) {
try {
    int keyCode = Integer.parseInt(keyCodeString);
    try {
        Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
        m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(keyCode);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        try {
            Process processKeyEvent = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(processKeyEvent.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("input keyevent " + keyCode + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: yes im using a service, and its check if something happened every 5 seconds, if yes the service send him to whatsapp, how can i highjack the keyboard to send the enter key command?

Comment: tried to use: inputKeyEvent("66");, 66 is the enter keycode but isn't working, tried on rooted device